# Sort post's categories by ID

Tags: categories

I have a blog in which several post's categories have to be outputted first before other categories. Those categories have lower ID compared to other categories. I am using `get_the_category_list` but it is not working as I expected. Makes me confused because I remember a theme doing this very well. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

```
<?php get_the_category_list( array(
  'orderby'      => 'ID',
  'order'     => 'ASC'
) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using wrong arguments for `get_the_category_list` function. The function you should use for this is `wp_get_object_terms` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms